FAILED_PRECONDITION: Request failed due to cold cache data on calls to google.people.v1.PeopleService.SearchContacts
I am using the google.people.v1.PeopleService.SearchContacts API to search Google contacts. I am following the instructions from https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchContacts that say to warm up the search cache before using the search API. Every request to warm up the cache fails with the error:

FAILED_PRECONDITION: Request failed due to cold cache data. Please try again in 5 seconds.

Repeated attempts after waiting 5+ seconds continue to fail in the same way. It seems that the cache warmup procedure is dependent on the cache already being warm. The same occurs when using Google's API Explorer:

This problem began approximately at 2024-08-02T00:30:00Z and has not been resolved in the roughly 14 hours since.
I have reviewed usage graphs and determined that this is not caused by quota limits or other rate limiting.
What is the cause of this API failure?

Since you are using the Test version of the API from Google Website and Getting this error. There is a strong chance that it is a bug. You can file a bug here at Google Official Public Forum this way a Google Support Engineer can help you take a look at this for you. Google Issue Tracker.

Thank you for that suggestion. I have reported the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/357017331

It was a bug and has been marked fixed by Google.
